# Spring Integration DSL: sending transform output to multiple endpoints

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

A legacy Spring Integration project defines the workflow using XML.
The basic flow is as follows:

1. `int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter` listens for a message and places it on an internal channel.
2. A transformer processes the message on the channel, and the output is then routed to three other internal channels.
3. Each of those channels is tied to an endpoint which will further process the output.

The following is the XML which ties the transformer component to the internal input and output channels:

```
<int:chain input-channel="inputChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="..." />
    <int:recipient-list-router apply-sequence="true">
        <int:recipient channel="outputChannel1" />
        <int:recipient channel="outputChannel2" />
        <int:recipient channel="outputChannel3" />
    </int:recipient-list-router>
</int:chain>
```

Am trying to represent this now as DSL.
The following is the basic configuration for endpoint:

```
@Bean
public DirectChannel outputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow listenerFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(inputChannel)
            .transform(transformer)
            .channel(outputChannel())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow outputFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(outputChannel())
            .handle(handler)
            .get();
}
```

Each endpoint is being represented as a separate `IntegrationFlow` bean. Is this the best practice, or would it be preferred to have one `IntegrationFlow` represent the complete workflow (if that is possible)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.routeToRecipients()` for the same reason: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-routers

And then have separate flows for each recipients.